# Opening Terminal in Current Directory

Tags: terminal, zsh, dwm, suckless-terminal

I am attempting to set up the behavior described in the title. For reference, [there is an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20673836/how-to-open-terminal-in-current-directory) which solve this for emacs. I however use DWM/ST and Zsh.

The solutions I have clumsily tried to come um with include modifying the .zshrc file in the with the following lined:

```
cd $pwd
```

I have realized this does not make sense as the path displayed by this instance of pwd will in fact be the path in which the terminal itself is opened, which is $HOME. Maybe the solution is messing with ST, but I have not had any ideas of how to do do so. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How are you opening the terminal? Neither ST nor zsh change the current directory (unless you put something a `cd` command in your `.zshrc` — don't do that), so the problem is with whatever you're using to open a terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this does the trick:

```
st & disown
```

EDIT:

You can make an alias to it and put it to your rc file (I don't know if it works on zsh)

```
alias st='st & disown'
```

So when you call it on the current shell it will open a new terminal on your current directory. Though alias are not inherited by subshells (you can define a function instead).

Maybe I misunderstood and you intended this:

There's this patch of st that let you spawn a new terminal on the current working directory with the ctrl+shift+return keybinding.

https://st.suckless.org/patches/newterm/

I think I'll patch my st too at this point.

Comment: st & disown did the trick! thanks!!

Comment: Same as `st&!` ot `st&|`.

Comment: Stéphane Chazelas is not the same as st&! cause if you close the parent terminal it will also close the new one you spawned.